# book suggestions for reading on saas design and implementation

Tags: saas

I would like to improve my knowledge on SAAS, its design and implementation. Most of that I found on a quick search were case studies and articles promoting SAAS. Can anyone suggest me some books to start with.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to start with reading the [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) article.